# Double Spacing and Margins conflicting

Tags: spacing, margins, line-spacing, setspace

I've got `\usepackage{setspace}`, and I'm having issues with my margins. When I use `\doublespacing` it adds a blank line before the first line of text on each page. Is there any way to have double spacing, but make sure that every time get a new page the text starts on the first line, and doesn't start with a double space?

For example, my first page has the chapter title at a 1 inch margin (where it should be) and the second page has 1 inch + 1 space before any text appears, but I need it to just be the 1 inch.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\oddsidemargin 0in
\textwidth 6.5 in

\topmargin 0in
\headheight 0in
\headsep 0in
\textheight 8.725in
\footskip 0.4in

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}{0 pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-.5 in}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
\chapter{Here is the chapter title at the correct spot}
In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I’ve been turning over in my mind ever since.

“Whenever you feel like criticizing any one,” he told me, “just remember that all the people in this world haven’t had the advantages that you’ve had.”

He didn’t say any more, but we’ve always been unusually communicative in a reserved way, and I understood that he meant a great deal more than that. In consequence, I’m inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores. The abnormal mind is quick to detect and attach itself to this quality when it appears in a normal person, and so it came about that in college I was unjustly accused of being a politician, because I was privy to the secret griefs of wild, unknown men. Most of the confidences were unsought — frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon; for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions. Reserving judgments is a matter of infinite hope. I am still a little afraid of missing something if I forget that, as my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat, a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.

And, after boasting this way of my tolerance, I come to the admission that it has a limit. Conduct may be founded on the hard rock or the wet marshes, but after a certain point I don’t care what it’s founded on. When I came back from the East last autumn I felt that I wanted the world to be in uniform and at a sort of moral attention forever; I wanted no more riotous excursions with privileged glimpses into the human heart. Only Gatsby, the man who gives his name to this book, was exempt from my reaction — Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn. If personality is an unbroken series of successful gestures, then there was something gorgeous about him, some heightened sensitivity to the promises of life, as if he were related to one of those intricate machines that register earthquakes ten thousand miles away. This responsiveness had nothing to do with that flabby impressionability which is dignified under the name of the “creative temperament.”— it was an extraordinary gift for hope, a romantic readiness such as I have never found in any other person and which it is not likely I shall ever find again. No — Gatsby turned out all right at the end; it is what preyed on Gatsby, what foul dust floated in the wake of his dreams that temporarily closed out my interest in the abortive sorrows and short-winded elations of men.

My family have been prominent, well-to-do people in this Middle Western city for three generations. The Carraways are something of a clan, and we have a tradition that we’re descended from the Dukes of Buccleuch, but the actual founder of my line was my grandfather’s brother, who came here in fifty-one, sent a substitute to the Civil War, and started the wholesale hardware business that my father carries on to-day...
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so I'm sorry if I seem terse, but do you have a MWE?

Comment: Did you mean `\doublespacing`?

Comment: @SeanAllred, Added.

Comment: The first line of the second page does start add the right height. The `CHAPTER 1` text however is above the text frame. I suspect that `-.5in` is the culprit. (Why is it there?) This also happens without `\doublespacing` or the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, `\doublespacing` is not the problem.

The problem is in the line

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-.5 in}{0 pt}
```

I don't know why you want to use such a feature, but if you change the second parameter to `-.3in` you should achieve your desired result:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-.3 in}{0 pt}
```

You can also change the value of `\topmargin` to `-.2in` so your chapter title starts at the same point as before in the page:

```
\topmargin -.2in
```

Comment: That is indeed it. The documentation for `\titlespacing*` made me think that the `-.5 in` was controlling my spacing after the title.